# Configuring Data in a tableViewCell on a button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am configuring a `UITableViewCell` with my coreData attributes. I am able to display the text.But i want to reload the cell with other data on a button click.

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Book *entity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 120, 21)];
  secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 120, 21)];

  firstLabel.text = entity.title;
  secondLabel.text = entity.author;

  [cell.contentView addSubview:firstLabel];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

  //On button Click i want to change firstLabel.text = entity.date and secondlabel.text =   entity.details

}
```

Comment: button is on the tableview cell??? or different button?

Comment: Then how will you identify which cell s data is to be changed?

Comment: All the cells have to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

Set global variale

```
int buttonCliked;
```

Set action for button

```
- (IBAction)aaaa:(id)sender
{
    buttonCliked =1;
    [_myTable reloadData];
}
```

Load the tableviewCell with data

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Book *entity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 120, 21)];
secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 120, 21)];

if(!buttonClicked)
{
    firstLabel.text = entity.title;
    secondLabel.text = entity.author;
}
else
{
    firstLabel.text =  entity.date;
    secondLabel.text = entity.details;

    if(indexPath.row >= [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] && indexPath.section >= [tableView numberOfSections])
    {
        buttonCliked =0;
    }

}

[cell.contentView addSubview:firstLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

return cell;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vinu.What should i do if i have 6 buttons.and I should configure them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

1) create a custom cell with ALL buttons

2) create an enum for every event you like (i.e. SendType, LikeType etc..)

3) create a protocol for your cell, and the delegate must be the controller 
for every cell.

4) action of your six buttons must stay in cell, and cell will invoke its delegate passing an ENUM for your kind of event, PLUS cell Ref.

5) controller will be invoked by the required protocol method, and decide what to do using cell ref and type of event.

i.e.
1) create a custom cell (ContactCell) and add:

```
property (id<TapOnSixButtonsProtocol>) tapDelegate;

  - (void)fillCellWithID:(NSString*)ID
             idContact: (NSString*)idContact
          withDelegate: (id<TapOnSixButtonsProtocol>) tapDelegate;
{
    self.tapDelegate = tapDelegate
```

2)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CustomTypeOfEvent) {
    Like = 1,
    Send =  2,..
};
```

3)

```
   @protocol TapOnSixButtonsProtocol <NSObject>
    -(void)didClickonCell: (CustomCell*)cell withType:(CustomTypeOfEvent)t;
    @end
```

4)

```
self.Btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.Btn1  addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(tapped:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.Btn1.tag = Like;
(repeat for all...)
```

..

```
   void tapped:(UIBUtton*)sender{
        CustomTypeOfEvent t = sender.tag // get back type..
        [self.tapDelegate didClickOnCell: self withType];
```

5)  in controller:

in: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ContactCell cell = [tableView dequeueReusable..
   [cell fillCellWithID: @"234444"
                 idContact: "67899999"
              withDelegate: self];


//delegate:
    -(void)didClickOnCell: (CustomCell*)cell withType:(CustomTypeOfEvent)t {
       switch(t){...
    }
```